# How to make an organized text document

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a D&D program for my friends and I. It is pretty much finished except for the fact that it is going to be extremely hard for my friends to add all their stats into the program. I am currently storing all the information for the persons character in a .txt document and calling it to my program as seen below.

```
labelCharisma.Text = line[0];
labelStrength.Text = line[1];
```

but the my problem being there is no format for my friends to follow. they would have to look in the code of my program, and find out what label or textbox correlates to which line on the text document. Is there any way for me to put a some sort of indicator in the .txt document before the value to show them what they need to put where in the .txt document?
IE 
(Line 0 is for Charisma): 16
(line 0 is for strength): 14
but when calling the line leave everything out but the value.
I realize this would be much easier to use a database, but at this time I want to keep it simple by using  .txt document.
Or is there a way to reference an .xlsx?

Comment: I would recommend you research whether XML or JSON formatted files would suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy format for settings is the good old [*.INI format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file). It looks like this:

> [Section1]
>   Setting1 = value 1
>   Setting2 = value 2
>
> [Another section]
>   Setting3 = value 3
>   Charisma = high
>   Strength = 2

While other formats like XML or JSON are more versatile and allow to build complex hierarchical structures, INI-files are easy to understand by everyone, even by non-programmers.

You can write a class for the access of these settings like this

```
public class IniSettings
{
    private string _filename;

    public IniSettings(string filename)
    {
        _filename = filename;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section, string key,
        string val, string filePath);

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key,
        string def, StringBuilder retVal, int size, string filePath);

    public string this[string section, string key]
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
            GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, String.Empty, sb, 1024, _filename);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, value, _filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var settings = new IniSettings(myIniFile);
string charisma = settings["Another section", "Charisma"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the technology you're using, you would probably want to use XML or JSON.
Both of these are structured text files, and have great support in navigating, accessing and extending its content.
If you're using Microsoft tech, I'd suggest using XML, and if it's a website type application I'd suggest looking at JSON. Personally I like XML more as I think it's cleaner and easier to maintain.

an example of how your structure will look in xml will be something like this...

```
<character>
  <name>Wizard King</name>
  <strength>3</strength>
  <intelligence>9</intelligence>
etc.
```

hope it helps.